# How to convert the Multiple select Query into Case Statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, case, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 3 select queries,

```
select * 
from PERSON 
where person_status_id in (8) and updated_on > sysdate - 30;

select * 
from PERSON  
where person_status_id in (5, 7, 13) and updated_on > sysdate - 30;

select * 
from PERSON  
where person_status_id in (3, 4, 6) and updated_on > sysdate - 30
```

I want only the count of 3 queries in a single query, so I have converted the query as below,

```
select distinct 
    v.cnt as "Completed",
    p.cnt as "Pending", 
    s.cnt as "Started" 
from 
    (select 1 as x, count(*) as cnt
     from PERSON w 
     where person_status_id in (3, 4, 6)
       and w.UPDATED_ON > (sysdate - 30)) v
inner join
    (select 1 as x, count(*) as cnt
     from PERSON w 
     where person_status_id in (5, 7, 13)
       and w.UPDATED_ON > (sysdate - 30)) p on v.x = p.x
inner join
    (select 1 as x, count(*) as cnt
     from PERSON w 
     where person_status_id in (8)
       and w.UPDATED_ON > (sysdate - 30)) s on p.x = s.x;
```

The above query using joins works as expected. It returns the count of completed , pending & started.

Now I want to convert to case statement.

```
select sum(case when person_status_id in (3,4,6) then (select 1 as x, count(*) as cnt from PERSON w and w.UPDATED_ON>  (sysdate-30) )v end) as Completed,
sum(case when person_status_id in (5,7,13) then (select 1 as x, count(*) as cnt from PERSON w and w.UPDATED_ON>  (sysdate-30) )p end) as Pending,
sum(case when  person_status_id in (8) then (select 1 as x, count(*) as cnt from PERSON w and w.UPDATED_ON>  (sysdate-30) )s end) as Started
from  PERSON w;
```

This shows "missing right parenthesis" error. Please correct me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a single pass conditional aggregation over the entire table.  The restrictions on `person_status_id` belong inside the `CASE` expressions, while the restriction on `updated_on` can go inside a `WHERE` clause, as it is shared across all aggregations.

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN person_status_id = 8 THEN 1 END) AS Completed,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN person_status_id IN (5, 7, 13) THEN 1 END) AS Pending,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN person_status_id IN (3, 4, 6) THEN 1 END) AS Started
FROM PERSON
WHERE updated_on > sysdate - 30;
```